# trigger event is not working in backbone.js

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, event-handling, requirejs, eventtrigger

Actually I am developing an application in which I am using following frameworks.

```
Backbone.js
Handlebar.js
Marionette.js
Require.js
```

Actually I am not getting how to debug this problem.

I have an trigger event in a view `MemberRegistrationView` like this

```
this.trigger("memRegForm:submit", memRegisFormData);
```

Now in my controller on this MemberRegistrationView object I have wrttien this handler in the controller.

```
memberRegistrationView.on("memRegForm:submit", function(data) {
                console.log("member submit event ");

            });
```

But the problem is that this handler is not getting called. Now how to debug this Actually I am new to backbone.

I have searched on Google but not able to find any help.

Comment: To trigger the event you probably want to use the jQuery cached `$this`, for example `$this.trigger("memRegForm:submit", memRegisFormData);`

Comment: @Jack: Probably not, jQuery events aren't the same as Backbone events.

Comment: Are you sure that `this` is what you think it is when you `this.trigger('memRegForm:submit', ...)`? Hard to know what's going wrong without more context.

Answer (score 1):

As a way of debugging this I would do the next steps:

1. Verify that the code works when the handler event is defined inside the View:

   ```
   var MemberRegistrationView = Backbone.View.extend({
     ...
     initialize: function() {
       this.on("memRegForm:submit", function(data) {
                   console.log("member submit event ");

               });
     }
     ...

   });
   ```

   At this step check whether this event is triggered from your view. If is not triggered, than is something wrong with your way of triggering. Place a breakpoint at your trigger line and make a debug - check whether you reach that line in your case.
2. If previously code is working, than is something wrong when the handler event is defined outside the View. I would do the next thing: verify that the event was registered on the view object - this can be seen in the **_events** property of the view object.

FYI - in backbone you have the Events module which can be mixed in every object. The View object already have it. The functions of this module can be seen at http://backbonejs.org/#Events

Comment: Thanks, checking the _events property helped me to see that my handler did not belong to the view but to another library's method altogether.